# different pasting behaviour in terminal

Tags: command-line, paste

I used 20.04 for a while, but recently upgraded to 21.10.  In 20.04, I could paste multiple lines of code into a terminal, and each line would appear as they were executed. This would begin as soon as I pressed "V" in the pasting shortcut.

In 21.10, various portions of the copied code appears when I press "V", and nothing executes until I press Enter.  I much prefer how things worked in 20.04 - are there any settings I can change to restore that behavior/workflow?